# Как изменить аргумент функции, так чтобы он был виден во внешней области видимости?

Tags: javascript

Функция `partitionOn` принимает 2 аргумента, `pred` — это функция задающая условия выборки элементов из массива `items`.

Функция должна возвращать длину нового массива с элементами удовлетворяющими `pred`. А также изменять массив `items`, который принимает в качестве аргумента.

В моем коде `items` не изменяется во внешней области видимости. Как сделать чтобы он изменялся?

В консоли пишу

```
window.items.concat(arrPredFalse, arrPredTrue);
```

и работает, но `codewars` выдает ошибку.

```
function partitionOn(pred, items) {
    var arrPredTrue = [];
    var arrPredFalse = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (pred(items[i])) {
        arrPredTrue.push(items[i]);
      } else {
        arrPredFalse.push(items[i]);
      }
    }
    items.concat(arrPredFalse, arrPredTrue);
    return arrPredTrue.length;
}
```

Comment: использовать вместо `concat`, который возвращает новый массив, `splice` который меняет массив к которому применяется

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2):

[Функция concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) в строке

```
items.concat(arrPredFalse, arrPredTrue);
```

Создает новый массив и возвращает его в никуда. При этом в исходном массиве изменений не происходит.

Присвоение результата той же переменной `items`, также не отразится на глобальном массиве, из-за того, что в этом случае просто изменится ссылка на которую будет указывать параметр items.

Чтобы изменения применились, нужно использовать функции непосредственно меняющие массив: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
items.push(...arrPredFalse, ...arrPredTrue);
```

или

```
items.splice(items.length, 0, ...arrPredFalse, ...arrPredTrue);
```

В примерах выше используется [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), упрощающий передачу массива в качестве списка параметров. Без его использования нужно использовать [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
items.push.apply(items, arrPredFalse.concat(arrPredTrue));
```

или

```
items.splice.apply(items, [items.length, 0].concat(arrPredFalse,arrPredTrue));
```